# Xiki on Windows: 'xiki' not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, xiki

Being thrilled by all the nice and promissing [screencasts](http://xiki.org/screencasts/), I followed the guides to install Xiki, summarized as:

1. Download/install [Ruby](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads)
2. Download         [DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit)
3. extract DevKit to (permanent) directory that has no spaces, e.g. C:\Ruby200\devkit
4. open command window in that directory *(shift-left-click, open command window here)* and execute:
5. `ruby dk.rb init`
6. `ruby dk.rb install`
7. `cd ..`
8. `git clone git://github.com/trogdoro/xiki.git`
9. `cd xiki`
10. `gem install bundler`
11. `bundle`
12. `ruby etc/command/copy_xiki_command_to.rb C:/Ruby200/bin/xiki`

Now, Xiki should be installed and opening a new command window and typing 'xiki' [should give some output](https://github.com/trogdoro/xiki#verify-the-xiki-shell-command-works), different from '*not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file*'...
I verified that 'C:/Ruby200/bin' is on Windows PATH (Windows+R, SystemPropertiesAdvanced --> Environment Variable --> Edit)

I seem to be very close to start using Xiki, just can't get there yet. What could be wrong?

Comment: If you are sure the PATH is correct then Restart your computer.

Comment: Unfortunately, @JoeDF, this good-old-solution for Windows problems did not help this time. There is a File called 'xiki' in the Ruby200/bin directory, but even executing `xiki` from this directory raises the exception

Comment: Really? Hmm then maybe it's another common windows problem... Does executing it like this `xiki.EXE` work? Or even the absolute path? `C:\Ruby200\Bin\xiki.EXE`

Comment: No, but the file also doesn't have an extension, it is simply 'xiki'

Comment: Well then, are you sure it's a windows executable? If so, then try renaming it to `xiki.exe`

Comment: I opened C:\Ruby200\bin\xiki with a text editor which revealed the contents: `load "C:/Ruby200/xiki/bin/xiki"` . This latter xiki file also exists, has no extension and can be opened with a text editor but has some more commands and text. Executing this file from it's location also does not work.

Comment: Ok, I see... You are gonna need a Linux style shell, try MinGW Shell or Cygwin then run it like so: `./c/Ruby200/Bin/xiki`. Also, xiki on Github looks different... https://github.com/trogdoro/xiki/blob/master/bin/xiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Xiki website](https://github.com/trogdoro/xiki):

*Supported platforms: MacOS and Linux. Pair with me if you want to see Windows support, support for your text editor, or just to hack on Xiki! (find me at twitter.com/xiki).*

The file in your Ruby directory is not a Windows executable.